# Assign Field based on Alpha Split of Contact Last Name

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, variable

Ok, so I have been searching for a while and I cannot locate anything that helps me resolve this scenario.

Business Scenario: I have a field "OSF Counselor" that needs to be assigned to a specific counselor based on the contact's last name. **A-E = Counselor 1, F-L = Counselor 2, M-R = Counselor 3, S-Z = Counselor 4.**

I am not that familiar with Flow formulas, but I believe I need to make a variable in a flow in order to identify the appropriate "collection" of records that match the alpha split and then update the record accordingly. The problem is I am not sure which function/formula to use to basically state the use case above.

Any support on how to start that formula would be most helpful, or if you know of what resources I can use to begin, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A formula isn't really scalable (ex. when you have more conditions, more counselors, to make frequent changes, etc), but if you simply have 4 conditions - *it can* work. You'd leverage [IF](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_if.htm&type=5), [CONTAINS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_contains.htm&type=5), and [LEFT](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_left.htm&type=5) to check the first letter of the last name. `CONTAINS()` allows you to use `:` between different values in the text argument to check against.

```
IF(
    CONTAINS("A:B:C:D:E", LEFT(Contact.LastName, 1)),
    "Counselor1Id",
    IF(
        CONTAINS("F:G:H:I:J:K:L" LEFT(Contact.LastName)),
        "Counselor2Id"
        IF(
           ....and so on
```

Important to call out that IF expects `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)` so there will need to be a default counselor if no conditions are met. The example screenshots are from a Record-Triggered Flow on Contact - your use-case may be slightly different (auto-launched flow, scheduled flow, etc) and necessitate a loop if you have a list of records to act on within the Flow.

[image]

The negatives of this approach would be:

- Having to version your flow every time you need to update this assignment
- Not easily accessible to see your assignment details - have to go into Flow builder.
- Will get unwieldy if you have lots of counselors. Formulas have a [text limit](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_field_limits.htm&type=5)

---

A different solution could leverage [Custom Metadata Types](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_overview) and [Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_flows) to store a table of your assignments.

- Create a Custom Metadata Type called `Counselor_Assignment_Rule__mdt`
- Create a custom field for "Counselor Id"

Then, create the necessary data to correspond to assignments

- Click "Manage Counselor Assignment Rules"
- Click "New" to create a record
- Create a record for each letter & counselor

[image]

Now, in the Flow you can simply "Get Records" that match with your current record and assign it.

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you so much! This is so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kris' answer

```
CASE(LEFT(Contact.LastName,1)),
   'A','Counselor1Id', 
   'B','Counselor1Id', 
   ..., 
   'F','Counselor2Id', 
   'G','Counselor2Id', 
   ... 
   NULL /* or 'defaultId', by definition, Contact.LastName is non-null but could have accented UTF-8 value or be a non-Latin character or even start with a number!
)
```